# Angularjs: adding user info to all request headers in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs web application and it has so many files. We use `$http` and `$resource` for get, post, put and delete. I want to add user info to all request headers from angularjs. In angularjs, is there configuration like this? Or any suggestion for aspect like solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use request interceptors for this.

See here for some examples: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/